# How to display in TextView a SharedPreferences string?

Tags: java, android, textview, sharedpreferences

I have a problem, I have completed all the code needed for saving a string in SharedPreferences with the help of an EditText and a Button but I have no idea how to retrieve and display it in a TextView permanently, below I have the code both for xml and java.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editt;
Button btn;
SharedPreferences sharedpref;
TextView textv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("name1",MODE_PRIVATE);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = editt.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
            editor.putString("name1",str);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
    textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple as:

```
// get the saved string from shared preferences
String name1 = sharedpref.getString("name1", "default value");
// set reference to the text view
textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
// set the string from sp as text of the textview
textv.setText(name1);
```

Put these lines into a new method, for instance `updateNameTextView()`, and call it in `onCreate` and in your click listener.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, it works fine! but why don't just leave it as it is without creating methods and stuff?

Comment: Just because 
a) when you start your app it should show the value from sharedpreferences
and b) when you save a new value it should also update the string in the textview :)
so you have two places and to avoid code duplication you put it in one place (method) and call this method from both places.